# Is there a way to change displayed buttons?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

Is there a way to make the displayed buttons keyboard keys instead of Xbox buttons?
Here is what I mean.

[image]

Like basicly, I mean the buttons used to guide you on what to press.

I use keyboard controls, so I want them to be accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without mods; no.

Basically the game has only got the icons for xbox installed.

Someone has [developed a mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/darksouls2/mods/30/?) for this however.

**Note:** this is currently not ready for SotFS, only the original.